# JAVA: How to print a user-inputted data in for loop?

Tags: java

I'm currently stuck and I don't know how to display the inputted data into 5 sections.
I've been assigned to display all of the inputted data which are name, age, height, weight, and language.
But im having issues on how to solve them.

my code is:

```
        String name = "";
        int age = 0;
        double height = 0, weight = 0;
        String language = "";
        int old = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            System.out.println("Enter Programmer Name>  ");
            name = scan.next();
            System.out.println("Enter Programmer Age>  ");
            age = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter Programmer Height>  ");
            height = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter Programmer Weight>  ");
            weight = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter Programmer Language>  ");
            language = scan.next();
            System.out.println("");
        }
        for (int h = 0; h < 1; h++){
        System.out.println("Displaying all programmers:");
        System.out.println("---------Programmer 1------------- ");
        System.out.println("Name:   "+ name);
        System.out.println("Age:   "+ age);
        System.out.println("Height:   "+ height);
        System.out.println("Weight:   "+ weight);
        System.out.println("Language:   "+ language);
        System.out.println("***************************** ");
    
        }}
```

The output that I want is:

```
Displaying all programmers:
---------Programmer 1------------- 
Name:   //name 1//
Age:   //age1
Height:   //h1
Weight:   //w1
Language:   //lang1
***************************** 
Displaying all programmers:
---------Programmer 2------------- 
Name:   //name 2//
Age:   //age2
Height:   //h2
Weight:   //w2
Language:   //lang2
***************************** 
Displaying all programmers:
---------Programmer 3------------- 
Name:   //name 3//
Age:   //age3
Height:   //h3
Weight:   //w3
Language:   //lang3
***************************** 
Displaying all programmers:
---------Programmer 4-------------
```

and so on.

This is the class i made

````
public class Programmer {

        String name;
        int age;
        double height;
        double weight;
        String language;

        public Programmer(String n, int a, double h, double w, String lang) {
            name = n;
            age = a;
            height = h;
            weight = w;
            language = lang;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public double getHeight() {
            return height;
        }

        public double getWeight() {
            return weight;
        }

        public String getLanguage() {
            return language;
        }
    } ```
````

Comment: 1) What you would want to do next, is to create a class `Programmer`, which holds all of the information you input as class variables (name, age, ... ). 2) Then for every iteration of your loop, you create a `Programmer` object with the input values (and probably store all programmers in an array of programmers). 3) At the end, you can print all of the information for each programmer. Edit: Seems like you already got step 1.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of type `Programmer`, fill it and print it, like this:

```
        int number_of_programmers = 5;
        Programmer[] programmers = new Programmer[number_of_programmers]
        String name = "";
        int age = 0;
        double height = 0, weight = 0;
        String language = "";
        int old = 0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        
        
        for (int i = 0; i < number_of_programmers; i++) {

            System.out.println("Enter Programmer Name>  ");
            name = scan.next();
            System.out.println("Enter Programmer Age>  ");
            age = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter Programmer Height>  ");
            height = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter Programmer Weight>  ");
            weight = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter Programmer Language>  ");
            language = scan.next();
            System.out.println("");
            programmers[i] = new Programmer(name, age, height, weight, language);
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < number_of_programmers; i++){
            System.out.println(programmers[i]);//You should ovveride the toString() of Programmer
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

            System.out.println("Enter Programmer Name>  ");
            name = scan.next();
            System.out.println("Enter Programmer Age>  ");
            age = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter Programmer Height>  ");
            height = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter Programmer Weight>  ");
            weight = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter Programmer Language>  ");
            language = scan.next();
            System.out.println("");
        }
```

Above part of code keeps overriding the same variables again n again 5 times. Maybe what you are trying to do is storing these attributes for 5 different people and then displaying them, if I'm right. So what you need is called an [array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

```
        String name[] = new String[5];
        int age[] = new int[5];
        double height[] = new double[5], weight[] = new double[5];
        String language[] = new String[5];
        int old[] = new int[5];
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter Programmer Name>  ");
            name[i] = scan.next();
            System.out.println("Enter Programmer Age>  ");
            age[i] = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter Programmer Height>  ");
            height[i] = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter Programmer Weight>  ");
            weight[i] = scan.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter Programmer Language>  ");
            language[i] = scan.next();
            System.out.println("");
        }
        
        for (int h = 0; h < 5; h++) {
            System.out.println("Displaying all programmers:");
            System.out.println("---------Programmer "+ (h+1) + "------------- ");
            System.out.println("Name:   "+ name[h]);
            System.out.println("Age:   "+ age[h]);
            System.out.println("Height:   "+ height[h]);
            System.out.println("Weight:   "+ weight[h]);
            System.out.println("Language:   "+ language[h]);
            System.out.println("***************************** ");
        }
```